# What are the intermediate steps of this integration?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

To provide some context this question relates to the determination of deflection $\omega(x)$ of a beam of length $L$ with elastic modulus $E(x)$, second area moment of inertia $I$ and bending moment $M(x)$. The second derivative of deflection $\omega''(x)$ is given by:

$$\omega''(x) = \frac{M(x)}{E(x)I}\tag{1}$$

$$\omega'(x) = \frac{1}{I}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{M(u)}{E(u)}\,\mathrm{d}u + C\tag{2}$$

I now suspect that integration by parts is used along with the boundary conditions that $\omega(0) = 0$ and $\omega(L) = 0$.

$$\omega(x) = \frac{1}{I}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{u}\frac{M(v)}{E(v)}\,dv\,du - \frac{x}{LI}\int_{0}^{L}\int_{0}^{u}\frac{M(v)}{E(v)}\,dv\,du \tag{3}$$

However I can not follow the integration steps from Equation $(2)$ to $(3)$. Can you elaborate on how this integration is performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no integration by part here, just direct integrate and set
$$C=- \frac{1}{LI}\int_{0}^{L}\int_{0}^{u}\frac{M(v)}{E(v)}\,dv\,du $$
In respect to the initial condition